# add item to right-click menu in Excel chart

Tags: vba, excel, menu, charts

How to add item to right-click menu in Excel chart using VBA?
Excel is 2007.
Chart is standalone sheet.

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty late, but I thought it's important for anyone else trying to do this.

In Excel 2007 and 2010, you cannot alter the context menus for charts and shapes. There are no errors, but the modifications just are not applied. Microsoft knows about this, at least the smart guys in the product group, but I believe there's nothing planned for these versions to address this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `CommandBars` collection, which is used for the context menus in addition to the toolbars.  There are at least three context menus - cell (right-clicking on any cell), row and column (right clicking on the A, B, C or 1, 2, 3 headers).  Very basic code for adding a new element to the row context menu is below.

See also the [MSDN documentation for CommandBars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432093.aspx), and there's an [old Office 2000 list of commandbar elements](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213552/en-us).

```
Sub AddToContextMenu()
    Dim element As CommandBarButton
    Set element = CommandBars("row").Controls.Add
    element.Caption = "Menu Item Name"
    element.OnAction = "VBAToRunOnRow"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you're not asking for a C# solution but I thought it'd be useful to post one since I just worked it out from Alistair's answer:

```
public void AddContextMenuItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application application, string label)
{
    var button = (CommandBarButton)application.CommandBars["cell"].Controls.Add();
    button.Caption = label;
    button.Click += button_Click;
}

void button_Click(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
    //Button click
}
```