# Excel VBA: Right click on a shape and add a new menu item

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, right-click

I am using Excel 2007 on a Windows XP Machine.
On my worksheet I have lots of 'Shapes' (Rectangles).

I have assigned macro's to the Shapes so that they perform a task when someone clicks on them.

What I would like to do is the following, but I've read posts which say that it's not possible.

- **When someone right-clicks on a Shape, is it possible to add a new menu item?**

It's easy to do this when someone right clicks on a cell, but shapes seem different.

I know that the worksheet has an event called 'Worksheet_BeforeRightClick' but I can't get this to work when I right click on a shape.

Below is the start of my code but it doesn't have any effect on my menu's.

Many Thanks in advance

```
With Application.CommandBars("Shapes")
    With .Controls.Add
        .Caption = "My New Menu Item"
        .BeginGroup = True
        .OnAction = "MyNewMacro"
    End With
End With
```

Comment: see [**`this`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157277/pause-macro-and-let-user-select-color) maybe you can play around with the code and make it work :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [add item to right-click menu in Excel chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040630/add-item-to-right-click-menu-in-excel-chart)

Comment: you can attach this kind of code to Right Click on shapes as `Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Shape, Cancel As Boolean)` and than check the target against a array of ranges like `If IsInArray(Target, YourRangeArray) Then ... `. **Still** this rises problems as it will trigger errors when you right click on anything else (like a cell), if not companied by some kind of error trapping like `On Error Resume Next`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, You want to add a macro that, when ran, would create another shape (?). IF that's true, you can run something like:

```
Sub AddShape ()
Sheets("YourSheetName").Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 35.25, 30.75, 121.5, 51.75).Select
'Add some additional info like name and style, or even attach another macro to it:    
Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "Test_Name"
Selection.ShapeRange.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset36
Selection.OnAction = "Testmacro"
End Sub

Sub TestMacro
MsgBox "Hello"    
EndSub
```

Comment: not quite. I want to right click on an existing shape and add a new item to the menu. I don't want to create a new shape.

Comment: @Eddie I've googled and tested many codes but I can't get any of them running on shapes (On Excel2010). I would say at this moment that it's not possible to add them to shapes. Thus, even if `Application.CommandBars("Shapes")` looks like a built in feature of VBA, it doesn't trigger anything. A workaround would be to create a Sub-Menu based "shape" buttons. With the 1st option being the original macro and the others your CommandBars options (?)